# POST size of request for lua nginx

Tags: http, post, nginx, lua, httpresponse

I try to parse post request using serer-side lua nginx([lua-resty-upload](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-upload)). In my case want to detect size of POST request(and files inside) beforehand. Is it possile to detect those length while request is parsing?Does HTTP-POST contain information aout its own size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Content-Length` header should be what you're looking for.